# want to add custom sound in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-notification

[i successfully add an sound into copy bundle.but the notification sound does not work in ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH1Nt.png)

Future simpleNotificationShow() async {
AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
const AndroidNotificationDetails('noti', 'noti notification',
priority: Priority.high,
importance: Importance.max,
playSound: true,
icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
channelShowBadge: true,
sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification'),
);

```
NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails, iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
  presentAlert: true,
  presentBadge: true,
  presentSound: true,
  sound: 'notification_.aiff',
));
await _notiPlugin.show(
    0, 'Simple Notification', 'New User send message', notificationDetails);
```

}

this is example of my code.